# Prism INavigationAware methods not called with WPF app

Tags: wpf, prism

We are using Prism 7.2.0.1441-ci in our WPF app. We have a problem that the INavigationAware
methods are not being called when navigating to a view. We use the below code to navigate.
The Login view is registered. The LoginViewModel has implemented INavigationAware

```
    _regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion(RegionNames.TabRegion, typeof(Login));
    _regionManager.RequestNavigate(RegionNames.TabRegion, ViewNames.Login, parameters);
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
       <DockPanel>
            <!-- <Frame x:Name="_mainFrame" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden" /> -->
          <ContentControl  prism:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static core:RegionNames.TabRegion}"  />
          </DockPanel>
```

This mechanism does work in another part of the app, this particular bit is in the startup code and is being called from the MainWindowViewModel constructor.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you register the view with the region _and_ (try to) navigate to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This mechanism does work in another part of the app, this particular bit is in the startup code and is being called from the MainWindowViewModel constructor.

You cannot navigate from the shell view model's constructor, because the regions aren't there yet.

Instead, do the first navigation from `OnInitialized` (or let the user click a button).

Comment: The navigation works, its just that the onNavigatedTo method is not called

Comment: Maybe because its in the createShell method we are getting some 'effects' How would I use the OnInitialised method in the MainWindowViewModel as that is where all this code is. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You could either navigate from `OnInitialized` directly or raise an event and subscribe to it in the `MainWindowViewModel` (if you had to do other things than just navigating)